# Вопрос по BufferedReader

Tags: java

Хочу реализовать простенький код, который будет выводить в консоль все то,что пользователь предварительно вводит в эту же самую консоль с клавиатуры. Написал следующее:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GrepAnalog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter the word");
        try {
        while(!buf.readLine().equals("stop")){
                System.out.println("entered string -" + buf.readLine());
        }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

    }
}
```

Он выводит введенные с клавиатуры символы,но почему-то выводит только 2 строку. Вот пример компиляции:

```
enter the word
dog
dog
entered string -dog
cat
cat cat
entered string -cat cat
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему он не выводит каждую строку, а только 2 введенную?

Comment: вы 2 раза делаете `buf.readLine()` сохраняйте в переменную.

Comment: вы правы,теперь понял.теперь после считывания буду сохранять.спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все достаточно прсто в строке `while(!buf.readLine().equals("stop"))` методом  `.readLine()` Вы вычитываете первую стоку, Вторая приходит к вам как и задумывалось `System.out.println("entered string -" + buf.readLine());` -отсюда

Вот пример рабочего чтения строки:

```
    try {
        String temp;
        while (!(temp = buf.readLine()).equals("stop")) {
            System.out.println("entered string -" + temp);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }
```

Comment: понял ошибку. спасибо.поправил,теперь все работает)